# How to create correct navigation with actions, using drawer and Navigation element?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an Single Activity app with ~ 10 fragments. Only one fragment can be on the screen at same time. Activity contains `DrawerLayout` with `NavigationView`.

Ok, so i want to create thing, when any fragments can navigate to one throw `NavigationView`, using their own actions. I called this fragment `Main`. So i want to navigate from Fragment1 to Main with action1, from Fragment2 to Main with action2, etc.

As i understand, i have two ways:

Hardcore, `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` in Activity and:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    ....
        case R.id.mainFragment:
            // a lot of code: define active fragment and using switch 
            // to making navigation with correct action
            break;
```

Or

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, controller, drawerLayout);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, controller);
```

I think second way is the only correct, but then a lose my actions, it seems like i just write:

```
case R.id.mainFragment:
    controller.navigate(R.id.mainFragmentName);
    break;
```

I use actions to add animations for fragment transitions, and i don't want to lose it. How to make my navigation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I complete it with Global actions, great for this task.